# Abnormal behaviour in ios7 uibarbuttonitem

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uibarbuttonitem

I have used a `UIBarButtonItem` in navigation controller. It look like as 
[image]

and my code was

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneImagePicker)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton];
[doneButton release];
```

I dont need white coloured box over Done button. How to fix it.

update:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it's style is being set incorrectly.

You should set it to `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` like this:

```
donButton.style  = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
```

Comment: your code included in project, build cleaned and still having the problem.

Comment: Very strange.  I can think of two other possibilities:  1.  You are setting the style later.  2.  You have another button underneath the done button.

Comment: check through out project... all uibarbuttonitems without back symbol having this problem... check my updated ques.

Comment: Are you using the appearance proxy anywhere to customize your `UIBarButtonItem`s app-wide?